# ConnectionString Timeout being ignored 

Tags: .net, windows-services, connection-string

I have a .NET Windows Service that references a particular assembly that makes calls to a SQL Server database. The connection string for these SQL calls is coded to pull from ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].

In the installation directory for the Service, I have a config file that contains the connection string "myconnection" and it originally had no connection timeout value and long running queries were undesireably timing out after 30 seconds. However, we see no difference by adding "Connection Timeout=300" to the connection string and restarting the service.

EDIT: The commandtimeout property is set to 300. Example below:

```
SqlCommand _command     = new SqlCommand(Sql, _con);
            SqlDataReader _DR       = _command.ExecuteReader();
            _command.CommandTimeout = 300;
            string _fieldValue;
            string _columnValue;

            while (_DR.Read()){ ... }
```

Comment: `The commandtimeout property is set to 30`.  What are we to believe?

Comment: @GreenShepherd - Try changing the CommandTimeout before calling ExecuteReader.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) to a higher value.

The [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) is how long a single sql command can take while the 
[SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx) is how long it can take to establish a connection to the sql server.

I don't believe the [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) can be set from the config file - it has to be set on **each instance** of the [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) itself.

Comment: @GreenShepherd - post your code where you are setting it, maybe it will help find the issue. From what you describe, it is the command timing out and not the connection. Also, if it is set to 300, are there queries taking longer than 300 seconds when the timeout occurs?

Comment: I posted the code in the OP. No, the queries are not taking longer than 300 seconds when the timeout occurs. In fact, there's a wrapper around this entire procedure which logs the start and stop times of the query and we can see that it takes exactly 30 seconds before the sqlclient timeout error is bubbled up.

Comment: @GreenShepherd - Try changing the CommandTimeout before calling ExecuteReader.